# Get array sub-element when the array name is unique in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, plugins

I have this array object:

```
//$array
Array (
[#insert_long_unique_id] =>
Array ( 
[0] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 770  
) )
[#insert_long_unique_id] => 
Array ( 
[0] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 530 
) )
```

The `#insert_long_unique_id` is an auto-generated ID and I dunno which method or plugin generate it but it's always different.

I need to reach and echo the `[ID] => 770` (first-element) only in my project.

Comment: you can use a `foreach` with a `break` inside it, just after getting the array element. That will result in getting the first element

Comment: @Kaddath okay but what about this non-reachable unique id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$id_array = array_column($array,'ID');

echo $id_array[0]; //print first-id

//In case if you want to print all ID's

foreach($id_array as $id_arr){
  echo $id_arr;
}
```

Comment: @MysticUnicorn  did you checke the answer?

Comment: Of course, the first answer. Yes I see, I give it an upvote.
Thanks for share

Comment: Only one thing that test my answer also for your scenario and if worked then use mine because it's easy and non-lenghty solution for you. The other-one is heaviour solution for you because of `foreach()` as well as multiple condition check.

Answer (score 1):

If your `array` variable name is `$array`, then you can access to `ID` inside of object like this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) { 
        if(!empty($value[0]) && is_object($value[0])){ 
            $myid = $value[0]->ID;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew that but the `#insert_long_unique_id` is always different
Sometimes like `b163cb25371a1b7c550d8f69fe211cc8` sometimes like `14f74cf38563b889386beeec511033e2`

Comment: @MysticUnicorn  check my answer below. it will work for your case